# javascript: change body height according to fit new content

Tags: javascript, html, height

I have a simple hierarchical menu, the first level items show their children when clicked. it all works well but expanding menu items make some of the other page elements to overlap each other. So I tried to change elements height but it's not working. here's my code:

```
function showSubmenu(id) {
        var container = document.getElementById("colonna1_hp"); //container not changing height

        var totalHeight = container.clientHeight;

        var list = document.getElementById("aree_tematiche_hp"); //menu container
        var prevHeight = list.clientHeight;

        //expand menu

        var currHeight = list.clientHeight;
        var diff = currHeight - prevHeight;
        var prova = totalHeight+diff;

        container.style.height = prova + "px";

    }
```

debuggind shows everything is correctly calculated and the new height is correctly set, but I don't see the result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us a working snippet/fiddle?

Comment: not really, it's quite a big page I won't be able to isolate a small working piece of it. so the code it's correct? should I search for the problem elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
document.getElementById("elementid").style.height = setHeight + "px";
```

or use jquery

```
$("#elementid").css({ 'height': setHeight + "px" });
```

Where setHeight is the height value and px is the unit.

An example working:

```js
var setHeight = 1000;

document.getElementById("iddiv").style.height = setHeight + "px";
```

```css
#iddiv {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 300px;
    border: 25px solid green;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "iddiv" >This text is the actual content of the box. We have added a 25px padding, 25px margin and a 25px green border. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

Comment: that's what I did

Comment: Your problem may be in your html, if you want help, display your html.